# What is wrong with this squid farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have built a simple squid farm on a minecraft server. Here is some information about it:

- It is a 8x8x8 water cube with opened fence gates below it, so squids can fall through
- It is located in Y:56 to Y:49
- It is built in a desert (hardly any water is around it)
- It is covered only by a layer of stained glass

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: Squid farm]

I have been AFK overnight on the server about 30 blocks away from the farm. There were no people on the server overnight, but for some reason, when I returned to the game, there were no items in the chests or squids in the water. Also, the entity counter in the F3 list shows a total of just 2 entities generated.

[Here is the world download](https://ufile.io/fdm4c)

What is wrong with this farm? Is there anything I should improve/add to this farm?

Comment: Are there any underground water sources perhaps? are you sure that there are no squid in the spawn chunks?

Comment: @D-Inventor There are hardly any underground water sources nearby, and the spawn doesn't have any water as well, as it is in a savanna biome.

Comment: Does this work if you re-create it in a singleplayer world?

Comment: Please attach a world download or a structure. We can't debug your whole build from just one picture. If you have no access to the server files or commands, please make images of every part instead.

Comment: If there are absolutely zero drops after a full night, then there's probably something wrong with your pickup system. Is there something in the minecart?

Comment: @Fabian I have tested the pickup system several times and it works perfectly. And no, there aren't any items in it, as it automatically unloads every minute. I will be including the world download soon.

Comment: The Wiki says: `Squids [...] can be found in any biome.`. I'd challenge this claim (provided that what you say is true).

Comment: May i just ask why you only built a 12x12 box, isnt a chunk 16x16?

Comment: @Petean I'm not sure what exactly is your question, but either way squid farms can be built in any size, as long as there is water. The size of the farm doesn't need to be the same size of the chunk it is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bit of a challenge to figure out.  The [spawning section of the squid wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Squid#Spawning):

> Squids spawn in water between layers 46 and sea level, in groups of up to 4 in the world generation and can be found in any biome.

This makes it sound like squid spawn in any biome.  After failing to get your farm to spawn any squid with multiple changes, I started reading the spawn wiki.  Part of the [section on java edition pack spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Pack_spawning):

> Desert and snowy biomes (except cold taiga) do not spawn animals other than rabbits.

**Squid do not spawn in the desert other then during world generation.**

Your problem is the biome it is built in.  You will have to rebuild in another biome.

---

The same section of the wiki also contains:

> Beach, stone beach, river, ocean, and mesa cannot spawn animals; only hostile mobs and squid.

You have a river biome right next to your current build:
[image: River]

I modified level.dat so spawning can occur, drained the river, created a structure of your current farm, and loaded that structure in the river biome:
[image: New Location]

As you see, this was successful.  Lots of squid.  The farm is not very effiecient as it requires the squid to swim down to the bottom to suffocate.  Some farms use flowing water so the squid are pushed out of the water.

The bad news is that you have to tear down and rebuild to move it.  The good news, you don't have to move it very far.

If you want to see it in operation first, [here is a download link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/p4lirl2oha3d9xk/MySqwidFarmMod.zip) to the modified world files.  It is named MySqwidFarmMod.zip and it is 2.4MB.

**tl;dr** Squid don't spawn in desert biomes other than during world generation.

Comment: The world I uploaded online is not a perfect copy of the server world. I have downloaded just a small part of it, and some data may have changed. This is probably caused by the world downloader mod. Squids spawn in oceans normally on the server.

Comment: @Quijibo I understand now.  I had overlooked that.  I spent some time figuring this one out and edited/changed my answer.  This one should help a little more.