# What is wrong with this squid farm ( not spawning )

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is wrong with this squid farm?

I have built a simple squid farm on a minecraft server. Here is some information about it:

It water cube with opened fence gates below it, so squids can fall through
It is located in Y:56 to Y:49
It is built in a desert (hardly any water is around it)
It is covered only by a layer of stained glass
Here is a screenshot of it:

Map link:[World](https://ufile.io/c67ad)
[image]

Comment: This looks like a very similar question to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330910/what-is-wrong-with-this-squid-farm). Does the answer there help you?

Answer (score 1):

Squid do not spawn in desert biomes. Although the [wiki suggest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Squid_farming) building a squid farm in a desert biome, it also states that the [rabbits are the only passive mob](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome#Desert) to spawn here (clearly a mistake on the page about squids).

I can only guess the suggestion to build in a desert biome is to get across the idea that you want to build where there is little natural water.

Comment: A river in/adjacent to a desert biome would be an excellent place to build a farm. It would however mean that you would be back to the problem of having to clear out a part of a river.